# Почему не загружается js?

Tags: javascript, ajax

В общем вот сам код

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#siting').click(function(){
event.preventDefault();
$('#content').load('html/SisTing.html');
  alert('Готова');
  //До сюда всё работает контент загружается.
  //Дальше как бы работет обычный js без згрузки скрипта.
var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
scriptEl.src = url // url = то ссылка на скрипт она правильная
document.head.appendChild(scriptEl);

});
});


</script>
```

Пробовал ещё такой вриант но бестолку

```js
t = d.documentElement.firstChild;
s = d.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "http://какой то сайт/js.js";
s.setAttribute("async", "true");
t.insertBefore(s, t.firstChild);
```

Comment: А $.getscript пробовали? Раз вы уж используете $.сделать_всё_как_надо()

Comment: Не срабатывает. Вообще результат нету.

Comment: Всё я разобрался в чём была проблема. Всем спасибо закрыт

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.
В jQuery есть для этого [$.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). На чистом JavaScript это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
scriptEl.src = url;
// если необходима функция обратного вызова, 
// то используйте scriptEl.onload
scriptEl.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptEl);
```